# "Well-received" question started to be a "good question" in asking badges' description

Tags: support, questions, badges, asking-questions

I noticed that in *asking badges'* description term *well-received* changed to *good*. What does this replacement mean?

I did some research in my badges and I found that I have the *Curious* badge since Apr 3. On that time I had just 8 questions with 5 zero-scored questions, but with accepted answers. Now, I have only 1 upvoted question, no more downvoted and my progress for badge *Inquisitive* is just *1/30*.

So I assume that zero-score questions were still *well-received*, but *good* means must have a positive score? Or I missed something?

Please, let me know if I confused, but this seems to me wondering and I cannot find the right words to explain what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: Zero-score questions were never well-received, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, I would agree, but I have a *Curious* badge since a few months ago and generally speaking, my questions got to be into a positive score just several days ago.... I didn't have even 1 question with >= 1 score. Mismatch :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

"Any open question that is not deleted and has a of score >= 1 is considered well-received"

It explains the formula as well. The wording may have been changed, but AFAIU the requirements haven't.

Comment: possibly, but still weird why did I receive the badge? I didn't have even one question upvoted... I don't believe it is a bug.

Comment: In my opinion, the change in wording from "well-received" to "good" invites confusion with the title of the [Good Question badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question), which triggers when a question reaches a score of 25.

Comment: @Yurets You received the *Curious* badge on April 3 at 11:45 by your profile.  Indeed, your 1 *remaining* upvoted question wasn't even upvoted until the 9th, 6 days later.  But on April 3, at 9:40, you received the *Student* badge for your first upvoted question, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2/student?userid=3810333).  The question shows no downvotes to counter the upvote, so my guess is that the (chain)-upvoter  was the user removed the following day - thus resulting in loss of many upvotes.

Comment: @OhBeWise, wow, you're right. I totally forgot about this, it was, I remember... Thank you for investigation. I totally lost that moment. :)